# How to Remove Previous li of particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this to remove the adjacent `li`, but it doesn't work:

```
   $(this).prev(".Removable").remove();
```

Edit: I only want to remove the immediate adjacent `li` if it has that class.

```
 WHEN SELECTABLE IS CLICKED I WANT THE PREVIOUS REMOVABLE TO VANISH

  <ul>

  <li class="Removable">   <li>
  <li class="Selectable">   <li>
  <li class="Removable">     <li>

  <ul>
```

Comment: Could you post some markup, and the event where you are executing the remove function?

Comment: Do you want adjacent or previous to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me: http://jsbin.com/esija/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Selectable").click(function(){
    $(this).prev(".Removable").remove();
    return false;
  })
});
```

But it only removes the previous sibling [as advertised](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev).

Comment: It appears that zsharp only wants the removing to happen when "Selectable" is clicked. Your code triggers when "Removeable" is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your html structure it's hard to tell the best selector to use, but you can try a catch-all traversal with `closest`, to hit the current `<li>` no matter where you start traversing from:

```
$(this).closest('li').prev('li.Removable').remove()
```

See [Traversing/closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest).

Comment: downvoted because this doesn't match what he needs, now that he's posted the HTML

Comment: @fudgey: actually this answer still works with the posted HTML. Maybe you misunderstood the question?